# Java - How to add a KeyListener to a UI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, key, listener

I wish to add a `KeyListener` to the entire UI by using:

`frame.addKeyListener(this);`

In `this` I have a working `KeyListener` so everything is good.

But, when I run my program, the `KeyListener` does not function correctly.

Is this because my UI is made up of only one `JTextArea`, one `JTextField`, and one `JLabel`? I have a feeling that I need to have some "background" of the UI showing in order for this to work.

Please help me with my situation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want to do with your key listener ?

Comment: Honestly, I am implementing the Konami code ... Sad, I know. =D

Comment: I meant what problem are you getting ? what you want key listener to do ?

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that the keyPressed() method is not being called even when I press keys ...

Comment: Added Swing tag.  You are using Swing components, right?  If so, see also [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply Key Listener to JTextArea or JTextField, **NOT** to Frame.

The method keyTyped() will be called when you will type some text in your JTextArea or JTextField.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know why I can't add it to a JFrame?

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337 As I wrote in my answer, the function will be called when you will type some text. You cannot type text in JFrame.

Answer (score -2):

We use for example `JFrame.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(java.awt.event.ActionListener, javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F12");` to listen to keystrokes from "entire UI".

Comment: -1 for recommending outdated api (use inputMap/actionMap instead)

Comment: ok, here's a link to new API http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/special_report/kestrel/keybindings.html